# Google Sheets IF, ISBLANK etc

Tags: if-statement, search, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying/failing to write a statement that returns a value of "Broken" if -500 is found in a cell, if the cell is blank then I want it to return "not installed" and then anything else i want it to return "OK" -

It feels as though i'm nearly there but strugggling - any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is what I have so far:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(E2),"Not Installed",IF(find("-500",E2),"Broken",IFERROR(find("-500",E2),"Correct")))
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer:

*You can use `SEARCH` in conjunciton with `ISNUMBER` to see if the cell contains `-500`, then use a second `IF` statement if it doesn't to determine if the cell is blank or not.*

#### Formula:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(-500,E2)),"Broken",IF(ISBLANK(E2) = true, "Not Installed","OK"))
```

**Rundown of this formula:**

- `SEARCH` returns the position at which a value is in a set of text. If it is not found, a `#VALUE` error is thrown,
- `IF` a value is returned from `SEARCH`, then `-500` must be in the cell `E2`.

  - In this case, it will display the string `Broken`.
- If a `#VALUE` error is thrown, then the formula will evaluate the second `IF` statement.
- If the cell `E2` is blank, then the formula will return the string `Not Installed`.

  - If it is not blank, it will return the string `OK`.

#### References:

- [IF function - Docs Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en)
- [ISNUMBER function - Docs Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093296?hl=en)
- [SEARCH function - Docs Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094154?hl=en)
- [ISBLANK function - Docs Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093290?hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(REGEXMATCH(UPPER(E2), "-500"), "Broken",
 IF(E2="", "Not Installed", "OK"))
```